# Github webhook returns 404 to my django app

Tags: django, github, webhooks

I'm trying to build an auto-deploy system with github webhooks where I commit every time I push to master, but I'm new to this and I'm struggling to make it work.

Goal: So far my goal is to just fire a github webhook and have a status 200
What I've done: I tried 2 approaches, I created a deploy.sh with this content:

```
echo "Hey it is deploying"
```

the webhook was set the following:

```
Payload URL: https://example.com/deploy.sh
Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Secret: ''(empty)
Enable ssh verification
Which events would you like to trigger this webhook?:Just the push event.
```

Outcome: the ping fails with 404 status and the response is the custom 404 page of my django webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I managed to obtain a successful webhook request with a dummy endpoint (which was simply returning 'Pong'), then I added a bash script to be executed when the endpoint is hit but I get permission denied even though I allowed the excitability.

api.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def deploy(request):

    # Verify if request came from GitHub.
    forwarded_for = u'{}'.format(request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    client_ip_address = ip_address(forwarded_for)
    whitelist = requests.get('https://api.github.com/meta').json()['hooks']

    for valid_ip in whitelist:
        if client_ip_address in ip_network(valid_ip):
            break
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission denied.')

    # Verify the request signature
    header_signature = request.META.get('HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE')
    if header_signature is None:
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission denied.')

    sha_name, signature = header_signature.split('=')
    if sha_name != 'sha1':
        return HttpResponseServerError('Operation not supported.', status=501)

    mac = hmac.new(force_bytes(settings.GITHUB_WEBHOOK_KEY), msg=force_bytes(request.body), digestmod=sha1)
    if not hmac.compare_digest(force_bytes(mac.hexdigest()), force_bytes(signature)):
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission denied.')

    # If request reached this point we are in a good shape
    # Process the GitHub events
    event = request.META.get('HTTP_X_GITHUB_EVENT', 'ping')
    print('the event is ',event)
    if event == 'ping':
        return HttpResponse(event)
    elif event == 'push':
        print('hello world')
        bash_file_location = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'deploy.sh')
        process = subprocess.Popen(bash_file_location, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
        return HttpResponse('the output is ', output)
    
    # In case we receive an event that's not ping or push.
    return HttpResponse(event)#HttpResponse(status=204)
```

deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Deploying'

cd /var/www/webapp/receipt_project

echo whoami
# pull master



git pull origin master
```

ls -la returns this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root www-data    315 Jul 26 19:18 deploy.sh
```

Webhook

```
Payload URL: https://recyppo.com/auto_hooks/deploy
secret: secret_key
Enable SSL verification
```

On the response I get a 403: Permission denied. I don't understand why I get it

Comment: I found out that the issue was related to the indentation of the else statement in the client IP check, moved the else statement on the left by one and the problem disappeared.
I had another issue because I was trying to return the output of the bash script as response and dajngo was complaining about newlines in the header, I added just a simple string and solved the issue.